# Is it OK to install a RPM built for lower OS version onto a higher OS version?

Tags: centos, installation, redhat, rpm, centos5

Our production server is running *sqlite-3.3.6-2* on CentOS release 5.2 (Final).

We're planning to upgrade SQLite to the latest v3.7.3 (atleast v3.5+).  But there is no RPM available in [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) website and not able to find one from google search also.

But I'm finding v3.5+ RPM for RHEL3 [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/12396267/dir/redhat_el_3/com/sqlite-3.5.9-1.el3.pp.i386.rpm.html).  Since we're running CentOS5 64-bit,

1. Is it OK to install a RHEL3 64-bit RPM package on a CentOS5 64-bit server?
2. In case, if it can be installed, will there be any implications/side-effects?

In general, can we install a RPM built for lower version of OS (ex: RHEL3) on a higher version of OS (ex: RHEL5)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer in my general experience is "if it works".  RPMs have depdency checking built in; they know if they need a particular version of glibc, or php, or mysql, or foo, bar or baz.  If you do an

```
rpm -ivh fribble-4.5.6-el3.i386.rpm
```

and it runs to completion, you're likely OK (though test it).  If instead it says

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libgwenhywfar.so.38 is needed by fribble-4.5.6-el3.i386.rpm
    libofx.so.3 is needed by fribble-4.5.6-el3.i386.rpm
    python(abi) = 2.4 is needed by fribble-4.5.6-el3.i386.rpm
```

that's RH's way of telling you that no, it's not going to work.  You can of course override that with `--nodeps`, but you'll be in for a lot of pain if you do, so don't; find an up-to-date RPM instead.

Answer (score 0):

The jump in this case is too large, and sqlite is present in the base repo. Rebuild from SRPM instead. Note that you'll be responsible for handling updates yourself should you decide to do this.

Comment: How do I build from SRPM in this case? Any pointers to relevant link/article are appreciated.  Also, I don't get your comment on `...you'll be responsible for handling updates yourself ...`.  Can you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: For the first, grab the `.src.rpm` file from the same place (more or less) that you found the `.rpm`, and use `mock`(available in the `extras` repo) to rebuild it. For the second, CentOS 5 supplies 3.3.6 and will likely never supply anything other than a 3.3.x version, which means that you will have to update the package yourself since you're installing a later version.

Comment: From SQLite download page http://www.sqlite.org/download.html, there are no SRPM.  They provide only 2 forms: Source code and Precompiled binaries.  I don't find `.src.rpm` file.

Comment: I don't see a .rpm either, so I don't think that's where you found it.